# iptables rate limiting with DENY instead of ACCEPT

Tags: linux, iptables

I know this is a weird question, but I couldn't find any solution out there. I have a problem where by having these rules(from `iptables-save`):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
```

All ports are open as long as they fit within the rate limiting rules. So, how can I make these rules deny all connections above the rate limit instead of allowing all connections below the rate limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: you should this rule to prevent blocking ongoing connections:

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

---

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

Now all matching traffic which is not accepted by the first rule will be dropped.

Comment: Where would the allowed ports go?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux Well, it depends if you want them to be subject to your rate limiter or not.  If **yes**, then before conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP.  If no line 1.  Either that or immediately after my suggestion if you choose to use it.

Comment: The problem is that all rules that fall within the rate limit are not subject to what ports are open or closed

Comment: @NerdOfLinux  Correct, because your rules aren't written that way.  **-m multiport --dports** add a list of up to 20 ports.  Add that to 2nd rule with ctstate NEW -m limit .  Also **-m tcp -p tcp** if you only want tcp ports.